# Has there been any evidence of Denisovan DNA outside of the Denisova Caves?

Tags: ancient-history, paleolithic

Is this the only known source of Denisova hominins genetics?

Comment: http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v512/n7513/full/nature13408.html